# Measure Path Length in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, software-recommendation, plugin

I'm using ***Adobe Illustrator CC*** to create SVG for my web animations, but the only tedious process is finding the length of each path lines in the generated SVG.

I tried Googling, but couldn't find anything related for CC Version(found for [CS6](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1075271?start=0) though).

So, Is there any tool(or plugin) which I could use to measure the length of `Path lines` exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: path length]

"You can view the length of a path in the sloppily tagged-on grab-bag Document Info palette. From its flyout menu, turn on Selection Only and Objects. Select a path and the palette will list its length, number of anchors, and other stuff."

Source:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/6326841#6326841